# How do I determine the type of a function?

Tags: haskell, types

Suppose I have a function like `map zipWith`, how can I determine its type? Given that the type of `zipWith` is `(a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]` and that of `map` is `(a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]`

Similarly how do I determine types of functions like `zipWith sum`?

Comment: Is the question about checking in ghci or about checking by hand/in your mind?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check the type in GHCi with `:t`, as mentioned in the other answers. If you want to try figuring it out yourself, you need to substitute the types as appropriate. In your first example, we have

```
zipWith :: (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]
```

and

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

The first argument of `map` is a function of one argument, so we have to regard `zipWith` as such a function:

```
zipWith :: (a -> b -> c) -> ([a] -> [b] -> [c])
```

(The type above is equivalent to the original one. It means `zipWith` converts a function which takes arguments of types `a` and `b` to a function which takes lists of `a` and `b`.)

`map` can be seen as a function of one argument as well:

```
map :: (a -> b) -> ([a] -> [b])
```

Now, we fill in the types in `map`'s result type - `a` becomes `a -> b -> c` and `b` becomes `[a] -> [b] -> [c]`:

```
map zipWith :: [a -> b -> c] -> [[a] -> [b] -> [c]]
```

P.S.: Do you really want functions which take lists of functions as arguments? If you just want to zip two lists adding the corresponding elements you want

```
 zipWith (+) :: Num c => [c] -> [c] -> [c]
```

rather than `zipWith sum`.

Answer (score 1):

You can see its type in ghci:

```
ghci> :t map zipWith
map zipWith :: [a -> b -> c] -> [[a] -> [b] -> [c]]
```

Similarly for `zipWith sum`:

```
ghci> :t zipWith sum
zipWith sum :: Num (b -> c) => [[b -> c]] -> [b] -> [c]
```

Comment: The latter type probably gives rise to a nice error as soon as you apply this thing :)

Answer (score 0):

That's what `ghci` is there for! Or you can just use [tryhaskell.org](http://tryhaskell.org/)

```
> :t map zipWith
:: [a -> b -> c] -> [[a] -> [b] -> [c]]
```